# how to remove error TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined, js engine: hermes on react?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing an app that so far has worked well and I haven't touched it for 2 days and now as soon as I tried to make it work it stopped working and it gives me this error I don't know what happened: I also tried to create a new one project and re-enter the codes but it always gives me this cursed error: iOS Bundling complete 76ms

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined, js engine: hermes
>
> ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

```json
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "5.0.11",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "cron": "^3.1.6",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-server-sdk": "^3.7.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"

    
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Your array, specifically is undefined because it does not exist from the item you get it. For example, item.array, item does not have the value array in it that why it is undefined.

Comment: Does the second error occur on iOS or Android? Regardless, try to build them both using `eas` for Android and `XCode` for iOS

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I hit this error, often what works for me is to just restart everything and clear my cache.

1. Stop Metro
2. Uninstall the app from device/simulator
3. Restart Metro with `yarn start --reset-cache`. Though in your case it would be `expo start -c`
4. Rebuild the app

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by cleaning the cache but not only did I have to remove some deprecations